# Friendly url only Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I got this...

> section_actual = $(this).attr('href');

and when i call the ajax in the end  i got this

> window.location.hash = seccion_actual;

then, i got this in the url

> http://www.example.com/index.html#seccion.html

The question is how i get this `http://www.example.com/seccion`
only with javascript

Comment: You're going to need to provide more code. Your question is a bit ambiguous.

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for the [HTML5 History API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History). See also, [Manipulating the browser history](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history) for a guide.

You'll want something like this, inside your AJAX success callback.

```
window.history.pushState({}, 'seccion', '/seccion');
```

Comment: this work, but i case if a load ajax content, how to do to refresh the url

Comment: Call the appropriate method from inside the AJAX success callback. You can use [`window.history.replaceState`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history#The_replaceState()_method) to replace the current history / URL entry, without pushing a new page to the history record.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
'http://' + window.location.hostname + window.location.pathname;
```